# RDLC and subreports insertion

Tags: rdlc

I have main rdlc report and rdlc file A , B

I want to add A & B in main Rdlc such that A in the first page and B in the second page any idea please

Answer (score 1):

Ok insert 2 rectangles in the main report. inside of each rectangle insert one of the subreport.

At this point go to the second rectangle properties and select insert pagebreak before

[image]

In this way on the first page you have the content of subreport A, and before subreport B a page break is inserted and you'll get it on a second page